# FileNotFoundException - Android - Creating and saving a pdf file to external storage

Tags: android, itext

I have a problem in my android app while trying to create a pdf file from view of app.

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyList/MyList.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I had an error such like above. What am I missing there?

How can I handle it? Can you help me? Thanks.

Here is the Manifest file of my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.furkan.tercihrehberi">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <!--activities...-->
    <activity
        android:name=".ListeMyo"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PDFGoster"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PDFGosterTeog"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
ImageButton save = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.save);
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                    Toast.makeText(PDFGoster.this,"You cannot do that.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                File pdfDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), 
                        "MyList");
                if (!pdfDir.exists()){
                    pdfDir.mkdir();
                }

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) PDFGoster.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pdf, null);
                root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap screen= getBitmapFromView(PDFGoster.this.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.tabla_cuerpo));
                File pdfFile = new File(pdfDir, "MyList.pdf");

                try {
                    Document document = new Document();

                    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
                    document.open();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    screen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    addImage(document,byteArray);
                    document.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT");
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(pdfDir,  "MyList"));
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

                Toast.makeText(PDFGoster.this, "List successfully created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does the file get created at least? I see you create the folder if it does not exist `if (!pdfDir.exists()){ pdfDir.mkdir();  }` - so does the file get created at all?

Comment: What can I do for it? I thought that I created file?

Comment: Try browsing through your device and see if the file exists in the location where you are creating it - the error says the file is not found - so just double check.

Comment: Both folder and file seems not to be created when I check the device after running that piece of code.

Comment: Try creating a file (in working directory) and then test your code (it should at least create the file). So instead of `File pdfFile = new File(pdfDir, "MyList.pdf");`do something like this : `File pdfFile = new File("MyList.pdf");` - this should at least create the file in your app's working directory.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. it should be something missing :(

Comment: What error are you getting now? Please also paste your Manifest file (to confirm your permissions).

Comment: I had no error but file does not created or can be shared. :( My project has already done except this part. I'm stuck on it.